# How to use float ** in Python with Swig?

Tags: python, c, pointers, swig

I am writing swig bindings for some c functions. One of these functions takes a float**. I am already using [cpointer.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn4) for the normal pointers and looked into [carrays.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_carrays), but I did not find a way to declare a float**. What do you recommend?

interface file:

> extern int read_data(const char
>   *file,int *n_,int *m_,float **data_,int **classes_);

Comment: I guess that the read_data() function takes these pointer-to-pointers so that values can be returned by them? You might consider changing the Python function to return them as part of the return value.

Comment: @Petriborg, The thing is, I have to return 'classes', 'data', 'm' and 'n' and I am not supposed to use a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a repost of one to a related question Framester posted about using ctypes instead of swig. I've included it here in case any web-searches turn up a link to his original question.

> I've used ctypes for several projects
>   now and have been quite happy with the
>   results. I don't think I've personally
>   needed a pointer-to-pointer wrapper
>   yet but, in theory, you should be able
>   to do the following:

```
from ctypes import * 

your_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("your_dll.dll") 

PFloat = POINTER(c_float) 
PInt   = POINTER(c_int) 

p_data    = PFloat() 
p_classes = PInt() 
buff      = create_string_buffer(1024) 
n1        = c_int( 0 ) 
n2        = c_int( 0 ) 

ret = your_dll.read_data( buff, byref(n1), byref(n2), byref(p_data), byref(p_classes) ) 

print('Data:    ', p_data.contents) 
print('Classes: ', p_classes.contents)
```